# Rails 4 update attribute (belongs_to) with click on link ( within dropdown list on show page)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have Issue model, which belongs_to Status model. What I need to do is to have dropdown list of links (or spans, doesn't matter) with Statuses Id's on Issue show page, so I could change status clicking on this (could be non-ajax and ajax).

I am rather new to Rails, so I do not know how to implement this, was thinking of few ways to do this, but non seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're new, I'll outline what I'd do for you (hopefully it will help):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :issues do 
    get "change_status/:status_id", to: "issues#change_status"
end

#app/models/status.rb
Class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :issues
    scope :not, ->(id) { where('statuses.id != ?', id) }
end

#app/controllers/issues_controller.rb
def show
    @issue = Issue.find params[:id]
    @statuses = Status.all.not(@issue.id)
end

def change_status
    issue = Issue.find params[:id]
    issue.status = params[:status_id]
    issue.save if issue.status_id_changed?

    redirect_to issue
end

#app/views/issues/show.html.erb
<%= @statuses.each do |status| %>
   <%= link_to status.title, issue_change_status_path(@issue, status) %>
<% end %>
```

There's obviously some stuff to explain - if you need me to do that, let me know and I'll give you the details!

Comment: Did everything You suggested - everything (except scope in model) seems clear, but when I start server I get "default_controller_and_action': missing :action (ArgumentError)" do not understand what is wrong with routes.

Comment: Where does the error suggest the problem is? Which controller?

Comment: It shows problem in my issues resourses on get "change_status/:status_id" line. Nothing else there.

Comment: Now server runs but I get 2 other errors :
"SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: scopes.id: SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses"  WHERE (scopes.id != 2)" 
in model
 and
"undefined method `not' for #<Class:0x000...>" in show action.


I commented out first and changed second to "@statuses = Status.all" instead of "@statuses = Status.all.not(@candidate.id)" and now get 


"undefined method `issue_change_status_path' for #<#<Class:0x00..."

Comment: Okay I had another error in my scope (sorry). I have amended that, but the error you have now is because the path helper we're using is not correct. Can you type `rake routes` into your cmd & let me see what you got? This will show us which url helper to use :)

Comment: GET    /issues/:issue_id/change_status/:status_id(.:format) issues#change_status

This one?

Comment: It should say the path helper ID in there - we need that

Comment: There is no helper for this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `link_to` rails helper like in the following code:

```
link_to "Change Status", my_path_to_update_status, remote: true, method: :put
```

This will send an `AJAX PUT request` (thank to the `remote: true`) to your `my_path_to_update_status`.

Then, you just have to update the status in the action corresponding to the path specified in the link_to helper tag.

More information about the `link_to` rails helper [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)